# Filter out URLs with any of some given file extensions

Tags: python, python-3.x, url

I wrote some code to filter a list of links, URLs, with multiple conditions given by file extensions. I want to remove every URL that is not an HTML file. The code is:

```
avoid = [".pptx", ".ppt", ".xls", ".xlsx", ".xml", ".xlt", ".pdf", 
         ".jpg", ".png", ".svg", ".doc", ".docx", ".pps"]

links = ["http://www.abc.com", "http://www.abc.com/file.pdf", 
         "http://www.abc.com/file.png"]

def analyse_resource_extension(url):
    match = [ext in url for ext in avoid]
    return any(element is True for element in match)

links = list(filter(lambda x: analyse_resource_extension(x) is False, links))
```

so that `links` finishes with `["http://www.abc.com"]` as only value. This solution seems kind of wordy for me. Is there any way to perform the same action without using the `analyse_resource_extension` function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strictly speaking, there is no direct correlation between the URL string and the type of the content you are going to get when following the URL - there can be, for instance, redirects; or the url leading to a, say, image file would not have the filename with an extension in it ([example](https://httpbin.org/image)). And, keeping the list of disallowed extensions does not scale well.

An alternative, slower, but more reliable way would be to actually visit the URLs (we can use ["lightweight" HEAD requests for it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16539269/http-head-vs-get-performance)) and check the `Content-Type` header. Something like:

```
import requests

links = ["http://www.abc.com", "http://www.abc.com/file.pdf", 
         "http://www.abc.com/file.png"]

with requests.Session() as session:
    links = [link for link in links 
             if "text/html" in session.head(link).headers["Content-Type"]]
    print(links)
```

Note that to improve on speed, we are also using the same [`Session` object](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects), which reuses the underlying TCP connection:

> ..if you're making several requests to the same host, the underlying TCP
>   connection will be reused, which can result in a significant
>   performance increase..

Demo (using [`httpbin`](https://httpbin.org/)):

```
In [1]: import requests

In [2]: links = ["https://httpbin.org/html",
   ...:          "https://httpbin.org/image/png",
   ...:          "https://httpbin.org/image/svg",
   ...:          "https://httpbin.org/image"]

In [3]: with requests.Session() as session:
   ...:     links = [link for link in links
   ...:              if "text/html" in session.head(link).headers["Content-Type"]]
   ...:     print(links)
   ...:     
['https://httpbin.org/html']
```

---

You can even take it a step further and solve it with [`asyncio`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) and [`aiohttp`](http://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html):

```
import asyncio

import aiohttp


@asyncio.coroutine
def is_html(session, url):
    response = yield from session.head(url, compress=True)
    print(url, "text/html" in response.headers["Content-Type"])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    links = ["https://httpbin.org/html",
             "https://httpbin.org/image/png",
             "https://httpbin.org/image/svg",
             "https://httpbin.org/image"]
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    conn = aiohttp.TCPConnector(verify_ssl=False)
    with aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=conn, loop=loop) as session:
        f = asyncio.wait([is_html(session, link) for link in links])
        loop.run_until_complete(f)
```

Prints:

```
https://httpbin.org/image/svg False
https://httpbin.org/image False
https://httpbin.org/image/png False
https://httpbin.org/html True
```

Comment: +1 much better answer than mine. Didn't know that you could determine the stuff with "Content-Type" either.

Answer (score 1):

> This solution seems kind of wordy for me. Is there any way to perform the same action without using the `analyse_resource_extension` function?

How about you keep `analyse_resource_extension` and instead use [`itertools.filterfalse`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.filterfalse):

```
from itertools import filterfalse
...
links = list(filterfalse(analyze_resource_extension, links))
```